# Uniqueness of classical solutions of nonlinear first order pde.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to prove that there is a unique classical solution (if it exists) to

$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_tu+A(u)\partial_xu=0, \quad t\geq 0, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x),
\end{cases}
$$
where $A\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. To do so, I take two solutions $u,v$ build their difference $d=u-v$, and note that it solves
$$
\partial_td+A(u)\partial_x d+(A(u)-A(v))\partial_xv=0.
$$
and according to [Lax' "Hyperbolic Systems of Conservation Laws and the Mathematical Theory of Shock Waves" (Eq. 1.4)](http://www.ingaero.uniroma1.it/attachments/1807_lax%20hyperbolic%20systems%20of%20conservation%20laws.pdf), one can see from this uniqueness since $|A(u)-A(v)|\leq C |d|$. What is the estimate that I need here, and can you sketch how to obtain it? I feel like we need a Gronwall like estimate. If I multiply with $d$ and integrate in space, I get an equation for the derivative of $\|d\|_{L^2}$, but I don't know what to do with the term $\int A(u)(\partial_x d )d$.

I guess I could also show uniqueness by the method of characteristics, but I want to understand this approach.

Comment: I think the author refers to Gronwall's lemma applied along a characteristic curve.